# Alamofire post request sending data as array

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

I am using a php based web service which accepts post variables. When I run it in postman it works fine but when I run it from Alamofire in my code the web dev says he is receiving the request in an array. Following is the request that server receives:

> {"{\"gameDate\":\"2018-03-31_12:43:37\",\"gameFee\":\"55\",\"gameInstruction\":\"\",\"gametitle\":\"ttt\",\"key\":\"AAAA\",\"latitude\":\"\",\"longitude\":\"\",\"numOfPlayers\":20,\"privacy\":0,\"status\":0,\"uid\":\"aaaaa\"}":"","0":""}

Following is how I am sending the request in Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            completionHandler(Result.Success(response.result.value))
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completionHandler(Result.Failure(.serverConnectionFailure))
        }
    }
```

param:

> ["key":appKey as AnyObject, "uid":event.uid as AnyObject,"gametitle":event.gameTitle as AnyObject,"gameDate":event.gameDate as AnyObject,"gameFee":event.gameFee as AnyObject,"gameInstruction":event.gameInstruction as AnyObject,"latitude":event.latitude as AnyObject,"longitude":event.longitude as AnyObject,"numOfPlayers":event.numOfPlayers as AnyObject,"privacy":event.privacy as AnyObject, "status":event.status as AnyObject]

How should I convert it to normal key-value request that php service accepts?

**Edit:**
my postman request that works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the params in form of Dictionary(i.e [String: Any]).

To convert class to [String: Any] :-

```
//Protocol for converting Class to Dictionary
protocol JSONAble {}

extension JSONAble {

    func toDict() -> [String : Any] {
        var dict = [String : Any]()
        let otherSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in otherSelf.children {
            if let key = child.label {
                dict[key] = child.value
            }
        }
        return dict
    }
}

//Request Parameters Class
class request : JSONAble {

    //MARK:- Properties
    var gameDate = String()
    var gameFee = String()
    var gameInstruction = String()
    .
    .

    //MARK:- Constructor
    init(gameDate : String?, gameFee: String?, gameInstruction: String?) {        
        self.gameDate = gameDate
        self. gameFee = gameFee
        self. gameInstruction = gameInstruction
    }
}
```

Use:-

```
var params : [String : Any]?

if let jsonableRequest = request as? JSONAble {
        params = jsonableRequest.toDict()
 }
```

=> Send this params as request.

Comment: I have tried, still web service is receiving same request

Comment: debug and check,, weather the class is converted into [String: Any] or not?

Comment: it is converted, I have checked it, only the request is received in a different way at server.

Comment: Send me the request,header and url at pratyushpratik@hotmail.com